# Creating typedef with arrays of structs

Tags: c++, typedef

I am attempting to solve problem 54 on ProjectEuler. For those who aren't familiar with it, it involves finding a winner for 1000 games of poker.

The problem I am having is that when I try to use typedef to make my program simpler and easier to read I get the following problem.

**Error**

```
pokerchecker.hpp:37: error: expected unqualified-id before '[' token
pokerchecker.hpp:38: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'Hand' with no type
```

This is followed by many other errors, but they appear to be caused by the above.

**Line 37 is as follows**

```
typedef Card[5] Hand;
```

**Full Header**

```
#ifndef POKERCHECKER_HPP
#define POKERCHECKER_HPP

class PokerChecker{
public:
    PokerChecker(){};
    ~PokerChecker(){};

    enum Rank{
        TWO = 2,
        THREE,
        FOUR,
        FIVE,
        SIX,
        SEVEN,
        EIGHT,
        NINE,
        TEN,
        JACK,
        QUEEN,
        KING,
        ACE
    };

    enum Suit{
        HEART,
        DIAMOND,
        CLUB,
        SPADE
    };

    struct Card{
        Rank rank;
        Suit suit;
    };

    typedef Card[5] Hand; // line 37
    typedef Hand[2] PokerGame;
    typedef short Winner;

    Winner EvaluateGame(PokerGame unsortedGame);

private:
    PokerGame SortGame(PokerGame unsortedGame);
    Hand SortHand(Hand);

    // each function returns the highest card (for comparing two similar hands)
    Card CheckRF(Hand);
    Card CheckSF(Hand);
    Card CheckFOAK(Hand);
    Card CheckFH(Hand);
    Card CheckF(Hand);
    Card CheckS(Hand);
    Card CheckTOAK(Hand);
    Card CheckTP(Hand);
    Card CheckOP(Hand);
    Card CheckHC(Hand);
};

#endif //POKERCHECKER_HPP
```

**Is what I am trying to do possible? If so, how/what is wrong with my current code?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The correct way to declare the array typedef is:

```
typedef Card Hand[5];
```

Comment: @joshuagerrard the general rule for `typedef` is 'pretend you are making a variable'